# Visual Studio breakpoint inside HttpClient.GetAsync call not getting hit

Tags: c#, asynchronous, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to debug an asynchronous call from a test script inside my .NET webservice, but the breakpoints inside my async call are never getting hit. I even tried putting a Debugger.Break() inside of it. Below is the calling code...

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseAddress"]);
        string uri = "/api/Rd_Regions";

        // Below is the line of code I want to step into, but it won't step into the 'client.GetAsync(uri)'...
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Convert the result into business object
            // Do stuff...
        }
        else do other stuff...
```

and the part of the webservice that should be getting called where the breakpoints are is here, the first is the context of the web api, followed by the method being called. I'd be happy if it stopped in either...

```
public partial class PIMSContext : DbContext
{

    public PIMSContext()

    : base(new OracleConnection(Security.ConfigurationReader.GetAppSetting("PIMS")), true)
    //: base(new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PIMS"].ConnectionString), true) 
etc....
```

And here is the method that is ultimately called:

```
    // GET: api/RD_REGIONS
    public IQueryable<RD_REGIONS> GetRD_REGIONS()
    {
        // I want the debugger to stop here!
        Debugger.Break();
        return db.RD_REGIONS;
    }
```

Am I missing something? Is it not possible to step into this asynchronous call? 
Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: are you debugging using test method? or thrrough web browser?

Comment: Yes I'm debugging the service via a test method in Visual Studio Online 2015. I'm building in debug mode and stopping at the line before the async call, and when I try to F11 (step into) the async call it just steps over to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to update with the answer earlier - it turns out I was accidentally debugging in Release mode (VS2015). Switching to Debug mode fixed it - all breakpoints started behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood you correctly - all breakpoints listed above are not getting hit? Not in await client.GetAsync(uri); neither in web-service GetRD_REGIONS() ? Is the code following after client.GetAsync not reached?

If it's true - maybe this method is never completed?

```
await client.GetAsync(uri);
```

Than it's possible that you are getting an exception in this place. Try to surround your GetAsync method with try/catch and place the breakpoint inside the catch block. Something like this:

```
...
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
try {
  response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
  throw e; //breakpoint goes here
}
...
```

Sometimes, because of your method is asynchronous, unhandled exceptions can't be registered globally by debugger or event-log. You can get this exception only with try/catch.

Comment: The only breakpoint that gets hit is the one on this line, that's where I try to step into and it just steps over...

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);  

I tried your suggestion thank you... unfortunately there is no error thrown, response.IsSuccessStatusCode just returns false and the code continues.

Comment: The fact, that you got no exceptions means, that HttpClient.GetAsync works correctly. Take a look at response object in debugger watch. Which http-status code is there? 404? 500? I think, that your second application can't handle the request. Maybe something wrong with routing / ActionFilters in your web-api? Try to check url /  routes and response object.

Comment: The response error is 404. I believe the problem is to do with the connection, because if you look at the context code line where I'm connecting to the database you'll see a commented line underneath where it used to be getting the Oracle connection from the connectionString... when it was doing that it worked, but I now need to get the connection out of a key using a ConfigurationReader... that is the only line I've changed and since then it's broken. I can't step into the line to see why it has been broken. Is it not possible to step into the GetAsync() call to see what it's doing?

Comment: You are calling yor's API method via http protocol. What is happening inside the controller is the other question. So, if the brakpoint in your API action is not hitted, it means that something happens before the request reaches this action.

Comment: 404 is caused outside of web-API application (on the network-level or web-server) or inside application, but before the action (for example in routing / databinding), HttpClient isn't the matter of the problem. IF breakpoint inside GetRD_REGIONS() isn't hit - it means that web-request isn't handled correctly. P.S. If you want to take a look at HttClient source code - you should use decompiler, because this class is declared in System-libraries.

Comment: Well, I know exactly when the error is happening, it is happening on the instantiation of the service context... because if I change the line where it is creating the oracle connection to the one below that is commented it works (I still can't step into the async call, but my service call succeeds). The problem is that I can't step into the instantiation of the service call bcs VS just steps over the async call.  I don't want to see the HttpCLient sourcecode, I want to step into my service call methods. Is this possible?